# Multiple execution times for a java program

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I ran a java program and calculated the time taken for a code to run. On multiple executions,I saw that the time taken keeps changing for the same piece of code. Could someone explain why? I used Eclipse IDE.

Note the times in consoles in below images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The jvm is working really hard for you dont put her on the clock!

also its nanoseconds not milliseconds, 459s would really be bad.

If you really want to mesure meaningful time do it on a scale where the background operations that grant you the privilege of coding without having to know what is happening on your machine and on which machine the code will be executed wont wheight as much. 1 second would be good enough